# Carla simulator example doesn't work well

Tags: python, simulator, carla

I tried to run automatic_control.py of the carla examples, but when I set --agent arg to "Basic" the program executes but the carla window doesn't show anything. Instead of this, when I set --agent arg to "Roaming" it works well. I was trying to solve the problem and I localized that the fail is in a function called "get_topology".

```
    def get_topology(self):
    """
    Accessor for topology.
    This function retrieves topology from the server as a list of
    road segments as pairs of waypoint objects, and processes the
    topology into a list of dictionary objects.

    return: list of dictionary objects with the following attributes
            entry   -   (x,y) of entry point of road segment
            exit    -   (x,y) of exit point of road segment
            path    -   list of waypoints separated by 1m from entry
                        to exit
            intersection    -   Boolean indicating if the road segment
                                is an intersection
    """
    topology = []
    # Retrieving waypoints to construct a detailed topology
    for segment in self._wmap.get_topology():
        x1 = segment[0].transform.location.x
        y1 = segment[0].transform.location.y
        x2 = segment[1].transform.location.x
        y2 = segment[1].transform.location.y
        seg_dict = dict()
        seg_dict['entry'] = (x1, y1)
        seg_dict['exit'] = (x2, y2)
        seg_dict['path'] = []
        wp1 = segment[0]
        wp2 = segment[1]
        seg_dict['intersection'] = True if wp1.is_intersection else False
        endloc = wp2.transform.location
        w = wp1.next(1)[0]
        while w.transform.location.distance(endloc) > 1:
            x = w.transform.location.x
            y = w.transform.location.y
            seg_dict['path'].append((x, y))
            w = w.next(1)[0]

        topology.append(seg_dict)
    return topology
```

Carla 0.9.5 on windows 10.

- Why doesn't it work?
- How can I solve it?

Comment: Code of this function please.